# Magit error on magit-remote-add

Tags: magit

On windows 7 version of spacemacs, with git layer, magit fails when trying to add a remote repository. After I enter the remote name, I get the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  string-match("\\([^:/]+\\)/[^/]+\\(\\.git\\)?\\'" nil)
  byte-code("\300\301!\302\303!\211\304\305\306\307\006\006\"\205\031\0\310\004\311\211\006\010\312%\"\313\314!E\207" [magit-get "remote.origin.url" magit-read-string-ns "Remote name" magit-read-url "Remote url" string-match "\\([^:/]+\\)/[^/]+\\(\\.git\\)?\\'" replace-match t 1 transient-args magit-remote] 11)
  call-interactively(magit-remote-add nil nil)
  command-execute(magit-remote-add)
```

git 2.9.3.windows.1, Emacs 26.3, dev branch of Spacemacs 0.300.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regressions has just been fixed, see https://github.com/magit/magit/pull/4158.

Comment: that was fast, nice