# Add remote from magit for new repo

Tags: magit

When creating a repo on a git server and wanting to push your existing local repo for the first time, how do I set the remote?

`M a` seems to not like me inputting the url, or a name like "origin". It gives me `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`.

The command line answer of exactly what I'm looking for is:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

How do I do this in magit?

The [magit manual](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Remote-Commands.html) seems outdated here because I can't find the `M u` option.

This might be related: [Magit error on magit-remote-add](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59297/magit-error-on-magit-remote-add).

Comment: It isn't `M-a` (`Meta+a`) but `M a` (uppercase `M` followed by lowercase `a`). Do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error RET` before doing `M a` again, so that we get more information about why that error occurs. `M u` is only available if `magit-remote-direct-configure` is non-nil and a remote already exists (or more precisely if `magit-get-current-remote` returns a remote).

Comment: Note also that if Magit is installed correctly then the manual is included and available at `C-h i g (magit)` and it will be the manual for the version *you* are using, whereas an online manual might be for a different version.

Comment: @tarsius thank you for the correction. I didn't realize the ambiguity and will change the OP. I was actually typing `M a` though. That being said, that must be the reason, I don't actualy have a remote set yet. So that would mean I have to use the command line to setup a repo for the first time? Will make that part clearer in OP too.

Comment: @phils awesome tip! Will use that moving forward!

Comment: `M a` should work when there are no existing remotes.  You linked to a similar issue which was fixed upstream... are you using a version of Magit that is more recent than that?  If not, then update Magit.  If so, use `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and add the stack trace from the error to your question.